# Graphviz graph to horizontal

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, dot

I have seen answers at stack overflow that suggest to use:-

```
rankdir="LR
```

but they didn't work on this script of mine.

```
from graphviz import Digraph


dot = Digraph()
dot.node('A', '(3904,1) (Input)')
dot.node('B', '(3904,64) LSTM layer 1')
dot.node('C', '(3904,128) LSTM layer 2')

dot.edges(['AB', 'BC'])

dot.render("a.gv", view=True)
```

If I add this line:-

```
dot=Digraph(rankdir="LR)
```

it throws error that there is no attribute of digraph named "rankdir".

I want to convert my vertical graph to horizontal graph, any help will be much appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```py
dot = Digraph(graph_attr={'rankdir':'LR'})
```